# Probability theorem, maybe with Moivre-Laplace

Tags: probability, probability-theory, laplace-method

I was given a very strange problem with not really much information but still thinking about it, here it goes:

> If 100 persons that enter a store and 70 from those buy something and 30 don't buy anything. Find the probability that if 10 persons enter the store, that 3 of them won't buy anything.

I thought it was with Moivre-Laplace and to find the probability of $P(X_k< 3)$ but that would be if at most 3 won't buy anything and I think i need if exactly $3$ don't buy anything. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the first sentence gives us the information about the (fixed) proportion of buying people, which is $p=0.7$

Let X the random variable of people who buy something, then it is binomial distributed as $X\sim Bin(10, 0.7)$

The question just ask for the probability that 7 (of 10) people buy something, which is $P(X=7)=...$. There is no Moivre-Laplace needed.

Do you comprehend my thoughts and can you proceed?

Comment: No, I have no idea what you mean? What do you mean by $Bin$...?

Comment: [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function) with $n=10$ and $p=0.7$.

Comment: @A.Cretan: They mean the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: So then the probability that $3$ people won't buy is that: 
$10$ choose $3$ $\times (0.3)^3\times (0.7)^7$?

Comment: What led you here and not use say for example the hypergeometric scheme or why not moivre laplace?

Comment: @A.Cretan moivre laplace: Not enough people and not necessary here. hypergeometric: From the information of the first sentence we estimate the fixed proportion. Therefore hypergeom. distr. is not the right one. With $p=0.7$ and $n=10$ we get $P(X=7)= \binom{10}{7}\cdot 0.7^7\cdot 0.3^3$. Are you familiar with the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{10}{7}$?

Comment: So how would you characterise some hints from when to use which distribution? (binomial, poisson, hypergeometric) based on the problem? And Moivre-Laplace only when there are a lot of cases?

Comment: >>And Moivre-Laplace only when there are a lot of cases?<< Yes. There are some thumb rules for poisson  and binominal distribution. But for n>30 you can apply the central limit theorem anyway. >>So how would you characterize some hints from when to use which distribution?<< If the probability of one event does not depend on another event then you use the binomial distribution. We have no information that the behavior of client A (buy or not buy) affect the probability that client B buy something.